# AWK pipe output from TTY to PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, debian, tty

I have a tty device (/dev/ttyUSB0), which occasionally outputs a string in the form of `Cycle 1: 30662 ms, 117.41 W`. I'm using a simple bash script to process it:

```
#!/bin/sh
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 57600

cd /home/pi
while true; do
 cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk '{ print $0 > "/dev/stderr"; if (/^Cycle/) { print "update kWh.rrd N:" $5 } }' | php5 test.php
 sleep 1
done
```

The test.php script looks like this:

```
<?php
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));

$file = 'kwhoutput.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $line;
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

however, the kwhoutput.txt remains empty. Why is this not working?

Comment: Does echoing $line produce anything?

Comment: How occasional is "occasionally"?

Comment: @glennjackman it depends on our energy usage, about every 20-30s. `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` works just fine.

Comment: @xxcezz nope, doesn't produce anything.

Comment: sadly I am not sure how to help much with the bash script... your php script obviously isn't getting anything from your bash script

Comment: Try your while loop without piping to PHP. What happens?

Comment: @glennjackman nothing, strange. Why would it not work, when just command-lining `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` does?

Comment: try `od -c /dev/ttyUSB0` to see if it contains what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is buffering your data. Use `fflush()` to flush  the buffers after each output line:

```
awk '{
  print $0 > "/dev/stderr"; 
  if (/^Cycle/) { 
    print "update kWh.rrd N:" $5;
    fflush(); 
  } 
}'  < /dev/ttyUSB0  | php5 test.php
```

Also make sure that `/dev/ttyUSB0` actually outputs a line (terminated by `\n`), and not just a string of data.

You should also fix up your php script to:

1. Read multiple lines and append them one by one (otherwise, the script will skip every other line).
2. Find out how to append to a file in php. Reading the whole file, concatenating a string in memory, then writing the whole file is not the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. However, the connected device seems to reset when it's doing an `fflush()`. It normally does this everytime you open a serial link to it. How can I prevent this?

Comment: To prevent opening the device over and over, fix your php script as described in point 1 in the answer. Alternatively, use a while read loop to call `test.php` over and over for each line: `| while IFS= read -r line; do php5 test.php <<< "$line"; done`

Comment: I don't see how the PHP script would fix that, as the device is opened in the bash script.

Comment: When the PHP reads one line and exits, awk is forced to exit too, and then the device is closed.

Comment: I was able to fix the device reset by using `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -hupcl`. I've changed the PHP script to `while($line = fgets(STDIN)){

echo $line;

$file = 'output.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $line;
file_put_contents($file, $current);

}` I do get the output from the serial device, but the output.txt still remains empty.

Comment: Never mind, it works now. I had disabled blocking mode in the PHP script. Thanks for your help!